# printf format specifier printing extra hex digits

Tags: c

I'm just combining two bytes into a 16-bit word, but some times I get a very unexpected output.

```
printf("TIME: 0x%02x 0x%02x = 0x%04x\r\n",data[2],data[3],rxTime);

$ TIME: 0x01 0xff87 = 0xff87
$ TIME: 0x03 0x37 = 0x0337
```

Here `rxTime` is just combining the bytes, and `data` is an array of `uint8_t`. What is really confusing me is that sometimes it prints 16 bits where I only tell it to print 8 (as above).

I can easily hide this problem by masking the bytes with `0xFF`, but I really don't understand why this would even be happening to begin with. I'm also not sure whether this is a problem with `printf` or whether somehow my array is being interpreted incorrectly?

EDIT:

A bit more detail, the data is being sent over a radio link, and on the transmission side I deconstructed the packet and everything is intact before being sent. There is hardware CRC and the link is good so it can't just be errors. Data is declared like this (its static to each callback function)

```
some_callback() {
    static uint8_t data[128];
    ...
}
```

I'm beginning to wonder if this might be some obscure bug in the embedded OS I'm using (Contiki).

Comment: `where I only tell it to print 8` - how did you specify to `printf` an int as 8 bit?

Comment: "data is an array of `uint8_t`" is doubtful,  Post the code that proves that.

Comment: @chux okay i added it in?

Comment: yep. using `memset` to clear the buffer doesn't change anything either.

Comment: Those extra 2 characters are certainly the sign extension of the 8--bit `data[]`.  Note the `FF` only occurs with the most-significant-bit  of the 8-bit `data[]` is set.  That is why it is so suspicious that the type is truly `uint8_t`.  Possibly the definition of `uint8_t` is incorrect.

Comment: It would be good post how code is "just combining the bytes" to form `rxTime`.

Comment: Well where the extra digits appear I'm just reading a single byte from the array, no combining has happened at that point. I'm away from code but I'll add it when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

Use the matching printf specifier.

With `uint8_t` it is `PRIx8`, `uint16_t` it is `PRIx16`, etc.

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("TIME: 0x%02" PRIx8 " 0x%02" PRIx8 " = 0x%04 " PRIx16 "\r\n",
   data[2], data[3], rxTime);
```

---

`PRIx8` is likely defined as `"hhx"` which will specify `printf()` to cast the parameter to `unsigned char` before printing.

Comment: [This doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46900123/102441), even though it should