# Why is <inttypes.h>'s PRIx16 not equal to "hx"?

Tags: c, printf

Why is [`PRIx16 == "x"` in C](https://ideone.com/veZfLN) (and [in C++](https://ideone.com/nuetzR)) under GCC?

I would expect it to be `"hx"`, so that the following works:

```
#include <inttypes.h>

int16_t v = -1;
printf("%04" PRIx16 "\n", v);  // prints ffffffff, not ffff
```

Comment: `PRIx16` is for `uint16_t`; you're misusing it.

Comment: On the other hand, `hx` is for both `signed short` and `unsigned short`, so this seems needlessly restrictive. Does another macro exist for `int16_t`?

Comment: C99 chapter 7.8.1, no PRIx macros for signed types.

Comment: I agree about [needlessly restrictive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900123/why-is-inttypes-hs-prix16-not-equal-to-hx/46901363#comment80747691_46900123), yet I do not see `PRIx16 == "x"` as non-compliant.

Comment: @Eric, what version of the [standard library](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120380/183115) are you using?

Comment: @chux, indeed, my lesdyxia got the best of me on that one.  VS2013 has it defined as "xh". Removing previous comment.

Comment: @chux: `ldd (Ubuntu EGLIBC 2.19-0ubuntu6.6) 2.19`

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

To print signed types use `d`, `i`.

To print unsigned types, use `x`, `u`, `o`.

---

`int16_t v` is a *signed integer* type.

`PRIxN` as in `PRIx16` is listed as a "fprintf macros for unsigned integers".  `PRIxN` is not listed for "fprintf macros for signed integers".  [@Kerrek SB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900123/why-is-inttypes-hs-prix16-not-equal-to-hx/46901363#comment80747487_46900123)

To print `v`, as decimal text, use `PRId16` or `PRIi16`.

```
printf("%04" PRId16 "\n", v);
```

To print `v` as a hexadecimal text, cast/convert to some unsigned.

```
printf("%04" PRIx16 "\n", (uint16_t)v);
```

---

I also would expect `"hx"` for `PRIx16` and that is the way with my GCC compilation (GNU C11 (GCC) version 6.4.0) yet this is more likely a [standard library version](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/120380/183115) issue (mine: ldd (cygwin) 2.9.0).  I have doubts about the up-to-date-ness of OP's compiler/library.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) {
  printf(PRIx16);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
hx
```

Comment: The cast is not necessary.  The OP's problem hasn't got anything to do with signed/unsigned bit interpretation issues.  "x" is out of spec, it should be "hx".

Comment: @jwdonahue I agree `"hx"` would be better, yet the C spec does not support that `"x"` is not compliant.  As [@Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46900123/why-is-inttypes-hs-prix16-not-equal-to-hx#comment80747924_46900123)  comments, there is no PRIx macros for signed types.  Thus OP's code is UB.

Comment: It's got nothing to do with the type. Look at the function signature: `int printf(char*, ...)`.  Whether you push an int16_t or a uint16_t, it's going to push two bytes on the stack.  The format string is interpreted by the code, which assumes you've actually lied to it, rather pushing char*'s all the way down.

Comment: @jwdonahue Your comment is a good reason why `"hx"` works (where certainly 4 bytes are pushed due to integer promotions), but it does not address the validity of OP's code that uses `"x"`.  C specifies `PRIx16` to be used with `uint16_t` and  `"x"` works with that.  C does not specify `PRIx16` can be used with `int16_t` - thus it is UB to use it with `int16_t`, even if it works on some platforms.

Comment: I would add that `PRIx16` is a macro, there's no type checking going on here, it doesn't even take any parameters to check them against.  Please edit your answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157329/discussion-between-jwdonahue-and-chux).